# Ajax - Checking for connection drops

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, networking

I am writing a Web chat application. It uses a long polling mechanism. Basically you send a request to the server, and the server holds it until there is data to send back. Then it responds, and then the client sends another request to the server. And the cycle repeats.

However, there is a problem - I have no error checking in place. What if the connection drops? Let's say I'm chatting with a friend and then my Wifi drops. Internet's down and let's say it goes back up a minute later. But then the long-polling mechanism has already died and with no polling, I have to refresh the page.

How can I implement an error checking mechanism to solve the problem of unsuccessful or dropped network connections? I am using jQuery to facilitate the Ajax requests if that helps.

**EDIT: Here is my JS code for the polling mechanism: **

```
// Polls the server for more data, basically a regular encrypted request
Minte.Network.poll = function()
{
    // If client is not connected, do not send poll requests
    if (!Minte.Client.connected)
        return; 

    Minte.Network.request({ "action" : "poll"}, function(data) {

        // If a client has disconnected and a poll returns afterwards, do not process it
        if (!Minte.Client.connected)
            return;

        Minte.Network.lastPoll = Minte.clock.getTime(); 
        Minte.Processor.process(data); 
        Minte.Network.poll(); 
    }); 
}; 


// Send a regular, routine encrypted request
Minte.Network.request = function(data, callback) 
{

    $.post(SERVER_URI, data, function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        data = JSON.parse(data); 
        callback(data); 
    }); 
};
```

Comment: Assuming you mean you're using `$.ajax`, you could probably use the `error` callback to work this out--maybe this function could call some repeating function that waits to reconnect. Can you show us any code you have so far?

Comment: Sure. Just edited my post and added the polling code

Comment: If the server is down is Minte.Client.connected set to false, or is that just a logged in/logged out check?

Comment: That's just a logged in / logged out check

Comment: @Ryan If you want to delete questions, flag them for moderator attention. Don't *deface* them. Why would you want to though? This site is supposed to be a resource for people coming after you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you can hook the error handling of the ajax call.  If it fails, you should eventually get an error condition back.  Since I haven't seen this defined anywhere, you'd probably have to work out a way to test how all the different browsers respond when the connection is lost in different ways to see if this is something you could use exclusively.  In any case, it won't hurt to hook the ajax failure response.  You will likely also want to implement your own timeout so that if you haven't heard back from the server in xx time, then there must be some sort of problem.

Second off, if you want quicker feedback and more likely to be consistent even in different browsers, then you can have your server return a heartbeat.  So, ever xx seconds of inactivity, your server would return a heartbeat response.  The client would wait, xx + yy seconds (yy is some extra to allow for roundtrip time and any slight lag in the server response) and if it didn't receive either an actual datagram back from the server or a heartbeat response, then it would assume the connection has died.  If it receives a heartbeat, it just makes another request again.  You can set the heartbeat to whatever interval you want, though obviously short times are more taxing on the server infrastructure.

FYI, jQuery has a global ajax error handler described here: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError#callback and the jQuery ajax call itself allow you to specify a timeout and an error handler.

In pseudo code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'xxxx',
   success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (data is heartbeat) start a new ajax connection to ask again
      if (data has returned data in it) process it
   };
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       some sort of connection error has happened
   };
   timeout: 2 * 60 * 1000;   // 2 minutes
});
```

Comment: Not saying it is impossible, but how would you code the JS to listen for the heartbeat?

Comment: The heartbeat is just an ajax response from the server - the server has to be coded to emit it if no other data is available.  When the JS receives the ajax response, it looks at the data and sees that it's just a heartbeat response, not a normal data response.  So, it just starts a new ajax connection.  If the heartbeat is not received in the desired time, then it assumes an error must have occurred.

Comment: That is not really a heartbeat. That is a client poll/server response. Configuring the server to send a message every x seconds would be superfluous, because the only way for JS to retrieve it would be by polling the server with AJAX which it is already doing.

Comment: @Aaron-I think you're missing the point here.  The OP asked for a way to know when the connection might have dropped on a long running server response.  Coding the server to always return something in a shorter amount of time, even if it has no real data to return is part of a potential solution to the OP's question.  I called it a heartbeat response which perhaps led you to expect something else - you can call it something different if you want, but it's designed to solve the problem of how do you know when the current connection has stopped working if the TCP infrastructure doesn't tell you?